# How i can see in-brower version of XCode reference? Wanna see list of methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, macos

I'm very like lists of methods in web version of reference.

But in Xcode I can't (at least by default) see this beautiful lists.

Can I change style of Xcode built-in reference? Make it show me in-browser version?

---

## in-browser

[image]

---

## in-xcode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't make "it show me in-browser version", but you can get a list down the side:

[image: screenshot]

Note that the fourth icon in the title bar is selected to get the contents.

To open all the subsections you click on the first disclosure triangle, the NSWindowCntroller line, that will collapse everything. Then option-click on it and everything will be expanded.

The divider between the contents list and the content can be dragged, so you can widen the contents list to see the full method names if you wish.

You can click on any entry to jump to that section, but it might not be smooth or fast – you will probably see the Xcode viewer re-parsing the source file! Older versions of Xcode were better, it's since been "improved"...

HTH